# Issue with sharekit

Tags: objective-c, ios, sharekit

I am using ShareKit in one of my apps. When I press the email (of FB) share button and the email view pops up, I press the home button. After that, whenever I start the app, and press Cancel->Delete Draft, my app crashes.

On Console, I see:

```
 *** -[UIImage isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7d3edb0
```

It crashes inside the SHK class in method

```
- (void)hideCurrentViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not dealloc an object, if you still need it. :-)

It could have several reasons: maybe you worked without ARC and you called `dealloc`/`release` to early, maybe you used the wrong memory management attributes.